# Append Element on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

### [Resolved]

#### Codecademy wasn't working with my script

I've looked up this question over the web, I've compared the code to other pieces of code that work fine, but nothing I do works.

What I want to accomplish is to create a div with the text added in a text area when the user presses a submit button. I don't need clean forms right now, or xss protection measures, I simply need this append a div when the user presses a button.

The code:

#### HTML.index

```
<body>
<div id="page-background">
    <div id="page-footer">
        <textarea id="input-box"rows='4' cols='24' placeholder='Input Text Here'></textarea>
        <button id='input-button'>Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

#### Script.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#input-button').click(function(){

        var userInput = $('#input-box').val();
        $('#input-box').val('');

        $('#page-background').append('<div>' + userInput + '</div>');
    });
});
```

The website: http://www.codecademy.com/JamesTill/codebits/DbczHl/edit

Comment: This is working fine for me. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kp3xg64v/)

Comment: Add jQuery script to your project. [**Your code**](http://jsfiddle.net/s74c706v/) works flawlessly when jQuery is there.

Comment: @Harben Nothing is happening when I hit submit. I thought my code was perfect, but it simply isn't working for me.

Comment: @phillip100 Excuse my ignorance, but how do I add a jQuery script to my project?

Comment: @James Check out [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp)

Comment: Look at the [*@Harben's*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28662042/962734) answer

Comment: It was working right, it was codecademy that wasn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## jQuery

Make sure you're linking to jQuery in your `<head>` tag or before your closing `</body>` tag.

```
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="page-background">
      <div id="page-footer">
          <textarea id="input-box"rows='4' cols='24' placeholder='Input Text Here'></textarea>
          <button id='input-button'>Submit</button>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I did this, but the code isn't working in both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: It's working, it's code academy that isn't working just right... Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript

```
var button = document.getElementById('input-button')
var pageBackground = document.getElementById('page-background')
var inputDiv = document.createElement('div')

button.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault()

    var userInput = document.getElementById('input-box').value
    inputDiv.textContent = userInput
    pageBackground.appendChild(inputDiv)
})
```

looks like codecademy isn't working right, but in any case, this is a way to get the same effect without jQuery.